# Applying Shader on RenderTexture Cocos2dx 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Could someone please guide me how could I apply shader to a RenderTexture in Beta 3.0,
 I used the following code to apply shader to renderTexture object, but the code doesnt seem to work anymore with Cocox2dX Beta 3.0

```
void TestLayer::initRenderTexture()
 {
    m_renderTexture = CCRenderTexture::create(utility::WindowSize.Size.width,utility::WindowSize.Size.width);


    cocos2d::CCGLProgram *pShaderProgram = new CCGLProgram();
    pShaderProgram->initWithVertexShaderByteArray(ccPositionTextureA8Color_vert, myFragSource);

    m_renderTexture->getSprite()->setShaderProgram(pShaderProgram);
    m_renderTexture->getSprite()->getShaderProgram()->addAttribute(kCCAttributeNamePosition, kCCVertexAttrib_Position);
    m_renderTexture->getSprite()->getShaderProgram()->addAttribute(kCCAttributeNameColor, kCCVertexAttrib_Color);
    m_renderTexture->getSprite()->getShaderProgram()->addAttribute(kCCAttributeNameTexCoord, kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords);
    m_renderTexture->getSprite()->getShaderProgram()->link();
    m_renderTexture->getSprite()->getShaderProgram()->updateUniforms();

    m_renderTexture->getSprite()->getShaderProgram()->use();

    //add renderTexture Object to layer
     addChild(m_renderTexture);
}
```

Thanks 
Rooma Thomas